# How can I rearrange a table to get a list of the existing combinations in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations, transformation

How can I rearrange a table to get a list of the existing combinations (in both directions) in Mysql?

For example, I have a table with two columns

```
col1    col2
1       5
7       1
1       2
```

I want to get a new table (added onto the existing table) where I flip col2 and col1.

```
col1    col2
1       5
7       1
1       2
5       1
1       7
2       1
```

This allows me to see all the values for each number, when looking both directions.

Like

```
1: 5, 2, 7
2: 1
5: 1
7: 1
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `select col1, col2 from tab union all select col2, col1 from tab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union`.

```
select col1,col2 from tbl
union
select col2,col1 from tbl
```

`union` is used instead of `union all` because the latter would give duplicate rows when a symmetric pair already exists in the table (for example the combination `1,5` `5,1`)

Then use `group_concat`.

```
select col1,group_concat(col2)
from (select col1,col2 from tbl
      union
      select col2,col1 from tbl) t
group by col1
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked in returning the result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use off a delivered table you don't have to create a new table. 
And you can make use of one query instead of using two queries.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col2) AS col2
FROM
    (SELECT 
         col1, col2
     FROM 
         [TABLE]
     UNION  
     SELECT 
         col2, col1
     FROM 
         [TABLE]
    ) table_data
GROUP BY
   col1
ORDER BY 
   col1 ASC
```